# Unexpected behavior when using eval in "find -exec"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, find

I was trying to batch rename and move a few files in a folder using bash when I ran into this strange problem.

I was trying to move each PNG file one directory up in the file hierarchy. First I ran:

```
find . -name *png -exec echo {} \;
```

and everything worked as expected:

```
./res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_pickonmap.png
./res/drawable-hdpi/ic_pickonmap.png
./res/drawable-mdpi/ic_pickonmap.png
./res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_pickonmap.png
./res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_pickonmap.png
```

Then I ran the following:

```
find . -name *png -exec dirname {} \;
```

which prints as expected:

```
./res/drawable-xxxhdpi
./res/drawable-hdpi
./res/drawable-mdpi
./res/drawable-xxhdpi
./res/drawable-xhdpi
```

But when I simply echo-ed the evaluation of dirname, It behaved very strangely. When I executed:

```
find . -name *png -exec echo `dirname {}` \;
```

It only prints dots

```
[blackvvine@unweeded-garden icon.bac]$ find . -name *png -exec echo `dirname {}` \;
.
.
.
.
.
```

Solving the problem of moving the files is not my intention here. I eventually solved it using:

```
find . -name *.png -exec bash -c 'mv $1 `dirname $1`/..' _ {} \;
```

My question is that **WHY this happens**. I always thought echoing the evaluation of a command is an exact equivalent to running it.

Comment: The original problem might have been solved more elegantly with `-execdir mv {} .. \;`

Comment: `find . -name *png -exec echo {} \;`, if it behaves as you say, is not at all behaving as expected.  I would expect it to error out with something like `ic_pickonmap.png: unknown primary or operator`.  The behavior you get is what I would expect from `find . -name '*png'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute this `find` command:

```
find . -name '*.png' -exec echo `dirname {}` \;
```

It effectively executes this command:

```
find . -name '*.png' -exec echo . \;
```

It is because command substitution, i.e. the part surrounded by backticks `...`, happens before `find` command executes, and `{}` is replaced by a single dot.

You can verify this by running `bash -cx` (debug turned on):

```
bash -cx 'find . -name "*.png" -exec echo $(dirname {}) \;'
++ dirname '{}'
+ find . -name '*.png' -exec echo . ';'
.
.
```

You can see `dirname '{}'` executed first and then `find` results are processed.

---

btw here is a better command to move files to parent directory if you run `find` from current directory:

```
find . -name '*.png' -execdir mv {} .. \;
```

Note that `*.png` should be quoted, otherwise it will expanded by shell even before `find` command executes.

Comment: @anubhava that's the thing, they don't produce the same output. Also, I'm not sure I've followed your explanation correctly but the PNG files are not located in CWD, so their `dirname` should not be `.`